# I wanted the TextView to appear over the Button instead of Under it. How can I do that?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want the text to appear on the button and not under it.And How can I give more weightage to the TextView rather than the Button background Colour.I was building an App TicTacToe and I came across this Issue.I'm not able to solve it.Can someone please guide me?

> Activity(MainActivity.java):

```
      import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.TextView;


     public class MainActivity extends
     AppCompatActivity implements    View.OnClickListener {

      TextView textone;
      Button button,buttonPanel;
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textone = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textone);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonPanel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPanel);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button){
            textone.setText("This is not Fair");
        }
      }
     }
```

> Layout(activity_main.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPanel"
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f4f18a"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/textone"
        android:id="@+id/textone"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button2"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: Do you want to set the button text itself?

Comment: can't able to understand the question correctly. provide some screenshots and explain.

Comment: I've two buttons. One at the center of the screen and the other at the right bottom. And the centerbutton has some background color. I also have a TextView on the centerbutton. Whose String value is null Initially. So when I click the rightbottom button I'm setting some String value to this TextView.But this is being hidden under the button. I want this TextView content to be displayed over the centerbutton.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have `<LinearLayout ...` as a parent of your layout, You need to add your `<TextView ..` and `<Button ..` like as below

   ```
    <LinearLayout layout_height=".." layout_width=".." orientation="vertical">
    <TextView layout_height=".." layout_width=".." id="@+id/textone"/>
    <Button layout_height=".." layout_width=".." id="@+id/button" />
    <!-- your other layout view -->
    </LinearLayout>
   ```

2.If you have `<RelativeLayout ...` as a parent of your layout, You need to  add your `<TextView ..` and `<Button ..` as below

```
     <RelativeLayout layout_height=".." layout_width=".." orientation="vertical">
     <TextView layout_height=".." layout_width=".." id="@+id/textone"/>
     <Button layout_height=".." layout_width=".." id="@+id/button"  android:layout_below="@id/textone" />
     <!-- your other layout view -->
     </RelativeLayout>
```